# Have I overused 'and'?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, syntactic-analysis

> *“Look - there’s nothing mysterious - or scandalous - about this business - at least not so far as I'm concerned. It's a perfectly straightforward case, and as it happened more than eighteen months ago - nearly two years ago - obviously it has nothing whatever to do with the wretched girl's suicide. Eh, Inspector?”*

(You can read this on page 16 [here](http://www.thehazeleyacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/An-Inspector-Calls-Full-Text.pdf))

Above is a quote from Mr Birling from the play *An Inspector Calls* by J. B. Priestley. I am analysing this quote; I wrote,

> Mr Birling strengthens his opinions by adding “perfectly” to “straightforward” (“It's a perfectly straightforward case,”) **and** “obviously” **and** “whatever” to “nothing” (“Obviously it has nothing whatever to do with the wretched girl's suicide.").

Have I overused the word "and" in my analysis? Perhaps I can put a semicolon somewhere and take one of the 'and's out?

Comment: it looks fine to me

Comment: If it were me, I'd look into reducing the number of quotation marks.

Comment: @MrLister good advice, italics would be preferable. as for the "ands" I don't see how they could be reduced without rewriting the whole thing.

Comment: It might read better/be a little easier to understand if you put 'adds' before "obviously". As in: 'and adds "obviously" and "whatever" to "nothing"...

Comment: Switching them around will certainly make it sound better! How have I not previously thought of that? Thanks, @Jelila!

Comment: I am not advocating switching em around, @QuartzX, I am suggesting adding the word 'adds' before "obviously". You'll need to retain the first 'adding' as well - so it's not really a swap - did I understand you correctly? Anyway I'm happy if it helps!

Comment: As a matter of style - which is always the author's choice - your overuse of dashes in the first quote fills me with horror. I would replace the first and fourth dashes with commas. Later on I would simplify to _... case, and as it happened nearly two years ago, obviously ..._

Comment: @QuartzX Have you transcribed your second quote correctly in your question? When using block quotes you should not add extra quote marks to show you are quoting something. So the first and last quote marks of both quotes should only be here if they were in the original. // My guess is you did this correctly and both quotes are dialogue in the original.

Comment: @QuartzX I do not mean to be harsh - **BUT** - I started reading your second quote and my brain rebelled. :) There were so many quotation marks that it refused to try and comprehend the meaning. However, there are usually commonly accepted alternatives to what you have now. If you want to work with me I will identify alternatives which CMOS declares to be valid.

Comment: About the dashes, I was just quoting how the author wrote it.

Comment: I find it satisfying to view things in a way that correctly follows a specific format, so the large amount of quotation marks there didn't confuse me. Though, it would be great if you can help me find any alternatives with fewer quotation marks.

Comment: Good answer about the dashes. Do you want to discuss your use of quote marks? Would you begin by stating whether the first and last quote marks are included in what you wrote.

Comment: Perhaps you should return in half an hour? I have have posted an Answer by then containing my suggestions. My "qualifications" are a number of amateur authors on another site ask for detailed reviews of their stories. I'll do what I usually do with your paragraph.

Comment: Everything written inside the first and last quote marks of the second 'quote box' (not sure what it's called) is a part of my analysis (what I wrote).

Comment: For something with a "block quote", you do not add anything extra to show it is a quote. Just copy your text verbatim into the block quote. // My answer assumes your question should not have the first and last quote marks.

Comment: Yes, my question was edited by another person, so I believe that they forgot to remove the quotation marks when they put the text in a blockquote.

Comment: Okay. So my answer now the answer I would give to your actual question, plus a bonus description of what you'd need to consider if that entire thing were words spoken by some character in fiction, or you had quoted it all from somewhere else in an essay but not used block quotes.

Comment: @QuartzX You have not commented for some hours. I'm going to interpret that as you not wanting to ask me anymore questions. Bye.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. I've been sleeping as I was in a more eastern time zone. Thank you for helping me reword my sentence; it sounds a lot better and a lot easier to read now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest your second quote be revised to read

> Mr Birling strengthens his opinions by adding “perfectly” to
>   “straightforward” (*It's a perfectly straightforward case*), similarly
>   with “obviously” and “whatever” (*Obviously it has nothing whatever to
>   do with the wretched girl's suicide*).

I have deleted the first and last quote marks from the quote in your question. It does not appear they come from your original.

However, if that entire quote was dialogue marked by double quote marks, I would place everything quoted within in **single** quote marks.

The usual principle is to alternate double and single quotes for complex quotes within quotes. Think of the way that parentheses are used to clarify complex mathematical equations: this works in a similar way.

It is quite common to use italics, instead of quotes, for examples within a complex sentence attempting to explain something.

This idea ended up down a dead end ... It is not invalid to begin sentences with conjunctions such as *and, but*, … Doing so has the effect of adding emphasis to that word, roughly equal to using bold font or italics. But, what the second sentence would then have ended up as didn't to justify that.

I continued looking for some alternative to your current structure, which has the form 'Noun verb A and B and C'.

My choice would be 'similarly with' to replace the first 'and'. It's optional but I'd add a comma there too.

I have no idea what was meant by: “whatever” to “nothing”. I changed that to simply “whatever”.

Comment: Regarding your last line: a part of the quote from the play says, "obviously it has nothing whatever to do with the wretched girl's suicide." So what I meant was that "obviously" and "whatever" were words that helped strengthen the character's point that 'it' has nothing to do with the girl's suicide.

Comment: I guessed your intended meaning correctly. That is why I deleted "nothing" from my suggested revision. The quoted sentence still makes sense if "Obviously" and "whatever" were omitted. Your intent was to explain the effect adding those words has on the sentence. In contrast, omitting "nothing" from the original completely destroys its meaning. I confirm I **would** reword your sentence as I have done so now in my answer.